# Grpc error: 2 "stream removed" while requesting server via haproxy

Tags: docker, proxy, stream, grpc, haproxy

I have a problem, when running requests to my grpc server via haproxy (which is located on the same environment) I received grpc error 2 - stream removed. I do not receive such error when requesting directly or when requesting via haproxy (located on another machine). Haproxy and server as docker containers.

Error:

```
    Exception message:  <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.UNKNOWN
    details = "Stream removed"
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1599567992.592358003","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:<ip address>:30334","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1055,"grpc_message":"Stream removed","grpc_status":2}"
```

My configuration:

```
    daemon

defaults
    log global
    timeout connect 10s
    timeout client 30s
    timeout server 30s
    option http-use-htx
    mode http

frontend haproxy
    bind {{haproxy_address}}:{{haproxy_port}} proto h2
    default_backend haproxy

frontend stats
    bind *:{{haproxy_stats_port}}
    stats enable
    http-request use-service prometheus-exporter if { path /metrics }
    stats uri /
    mode http

backend haproxy
   server performance {{server_address}}:{{server_port}} proto h2
```